# Showing the string '\u' in javadoc in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

How can I add the following string to javadoc?

```
C:\users
```

The prolbem is that \u is a Unicode prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not pretty in code, but working in the javadoc popups (and html output)

```
/**
 * C:&#92;users
 */
```

'&#92;' is the html character for a '\'

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you substitute the backslash with the HTML entity `&#92;`?

Answer (score 0):

`<pre>` tag enables you to include a code snippet in javadoc, so you could do something like:

```
<pre>
    C:\users
</pre>
```

Here's the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html

Comment: the problem is with the '\u' and adding tags around it doesn't help.